# How to submit a Dask job to a remote Kubernetes cluster from local machine

Tags: kubernetes, dask, dask-distributed

I have a Kubernetes cluster set up using Kubernetes Engine on GCP. I have also installed Dask using the Helm package manager. My data are stored in a Google Storage bucket on GCP.

Running `kubectl get services` on my local machine yields the following output

[image]

I can open the dashboard and jupyter notebook using the external IP without any problems. However, I'd like to develop a workflow where I write code in my local machine and submit the script to the remote cluster and run it there.

**How can I do this?**

I tried following the instructions in [Submitting Applications](http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/submitting-applications.html) using `dask-remote`. I also tried exposing the scheduler using `kubectl expose deployment` with type LoadBalancer, though I do not know if I did this correctly. Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your client and workers share the same software environment then you should be able to connect a client to a remote scheduler using the publicly visible IP.

```
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client('REDACTED_EXTERNAL_SCHEDULER_IP')
```